# How do i setup my React app using electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, electron

I use webpack to bundle my React app, it emits static files like the index.html, app.js, vendors.js and resource files. Then I simply throw them to a nginx server, and it works. Now I just start playing with Electron, and I can start a dev server for the app and then start electron, so it works. But I'm wondering how do I make it to production and package it. Do I also need a server to run my app? Like having a naught server to support my app in the electron environment...than what if the server is down, I don't think that's the solution. However, if I simply throw the static files into the electron environment, it reads the js files, but doesn't run it.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? Struggling with this now